# Centre Wordpress Button

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to centre a button on my [site](http://theloyaltycloud.com):

(scroll to Features, notice the Read More button)

The code on the Wordpress text editor for features section is below:

```
[vc_row title="Features" title_underline="underline" subtitle="Angle is a uniquely designed wordpress theme. It's super easy to modify and uses advanced CSS techniques built on the latest Bootstrap Framework. " title_size="super" title_weight="hairline" title_align="center" swatch="swatch-red-white" width="padded" overlay_opacity="0" background_image_size="cover" background_image_repeat="no-repeat" background_image_attachment="scroll" overlay_colour="0.4" top_decoration="clouds" bottom_decoration="none" height="normal" background_position_vertical="0" overlay_grid="off"][vc_column width="1/1"][services style="horizontal" connected="hide" show_titles="show" link_titles="on" show_images="show" link_images="on" show_excerpts="show" align_excerpts="center" show_readmores="hide" category="frontpage-services" count="4" columns="4" image_shape="round" image_size="normal" image_shadow="show" readmore_text="Read more"][button type="link" size="lg" link_open="_self" show_icon="no-icon" icon="cloud" title="Read More" link="/features"][/vc_column][/vc_row]
```

Could someone explain how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
<div class="text-center">
<a class="btn btn-link btn-lg" target="_self" href="/features">Read More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Kiran, thanks for your help! Silly question but in which file do I need to enter this?

Comment: This read more is coming under "Features". So try to search in which file you have "Features" word and replace the mentioned code there. don't know exactly :-( its correct or not. try this hope you can fix with this

Comment: Thanks Kiran i've finally solved it! I appreciate your help and wish you all the best!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `<a>` inside `<div>`

```
<div class="text-center">
<a href="/features" class="btn btn-link btn-lg _center" target="_self">Read More</a>
</div>
```

and give `text-align: center` to `.text-center`

Answer (score 0):

You can just update as

**Old Markup**

```
<a href="/features" class="btn btn-link btn-lg _center" target="_self">Read More</a>
```

**New Markup**

```
<p class="text-center">
        <a target="_self" class="btn btn-link btn-lg _center" href="/features">Read More</a> </p>
```

as you have allready css defined for class="text-center" you dont have to add extra efforts in css

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways.

## First

Wrap the read more button in a `<div>` and give `text-align: center` to `<div>`

```
<div class="text-center">
<a href="/features" class="btn btn-link btn-lg _center" target="_self">Read More</a>
</div>

.text-center {
text-align: center;
}
```

## Second

Give following CSS to read more button.

```
.swatch-red-white a { 
display: block;
width: 120px;
margin: 0 auto;}
```